# showing and hiding a input in a ngfor to edit the value with angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to do a simple list of items :

[image]

for that, i use a mat-list containing a span for reading mode and an input in edition mode. I'm using the attribut hidden of the span like a boolean to switch between the two modes. I vould like to switch in reading mode if the focus of the input is lost, so i used the (blur) :

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of list">
    <span #itemDisplay >{{item}}</span>
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="itemDisplay.hidden">
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="updateItem" [formControl]="updateItemFormControl" [hidden]="!itemDisplay.hidden" (blur)="itemDisplay.hidden=false;" minlength="3" maxlength="10" autofocus #edit>
    <mat-error *ngIf="updateItemFormControl.hasError('required')">
      add label to your item
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="updateItemFormControl.hasError('minlength')">
      min 3 caracters
    </mat-error>
    <mat-hint align="end">{{edit.value.length}} / 128</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-icon-button (mousedown)="changeItem(list.indexOf(item)); itemDisplay.hidden = false;" *ngIf="itemDisplay.hidden"><mat-icon>check_circle</mat-icon></button>
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="updateItem='';itemDisplay.hidden = true;" *ngIf="!itemDisplay.hidden"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></button>
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="list.splice(list.indexOf(item), 1)" *ngIf="!itemDisplay.hidden"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-list-item>

  <mat-list>
    <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="newItem" [formControl]="newItemFormControl" placeholder="Add item" minlength="3" maxlength="10" #add>
    <mat-error *ngIf="newItemFormControl.hasError('required')">
      add label to your item
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="newItemFormControl.hasError('minlength')">
      min 3 caracters
    </mat-error>
    <mat-hint align="end">{{add.value.length}} / 128</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="list.push(newItem);newItem=''" [hidden]="false" [disabled]="!newItemFormControl.valid">
      <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-list>
</mat-list>
```

it works fine the first time i click on the edit button but the second time, it doesn't take the focus. And after the second time i can have two inputs in the same time. Noramlly, the blur is supposed to switch the itemDisplay.hidden to false and hidding the span.

I wanted to do the logical without a lot of things in the code side. do you understand the problem ?

that's my typescript :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'list-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'list-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['list-overview-example.css'],
})
export class ListOverviewExample {

  list:Array<string> = ['item 1','item 2','item 3'] ;
  newItemFormControl: FormControl = new FormControl(this.newItem,[
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(4),
    Validators.maxLength(128)
  ]) ;
  updateItemFormControl: FormControl = new FormControl(this.updateItem,[
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(4),
    Validators.maxLength(128)
  ]) ;

  newItem: string ;
  updateItem: string;

  changeItem(i){
    this.list[i] = this.updateItem ;
    this.updateItem = '';
  }

}
```

here is the stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xoxuzn

Comment: Could you please provide a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) for it ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, Angular is re-iterating over the list if any change is detected in array. You should use `trackBy` to tell the angular what is changed exactly so that it will update the line item which is really changed. Because of this reconstruction of entire view, you are loosing the focus.

Make the below changes

### html

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of list; trackBy:trackByIndex">
```

### ts

```
 trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i changed this in the stackblitz but has you can see, the input get the focus the first time you click on the edit button, but if you click outside the input and you try again to edit, it doesn't get the focus on the second time.